# TypeError & AssertionError when clicking on buttons in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Apologies for the long post, I am trying to implement a simple button which either add or remove an item from a watchlist.

While I initially managed to implement the "addwatchlist" function appropriately, I tinkered my code for a few hours and I somewhat am unable to wrap my head around it again.

Here is the error that I receive when pressing the **"Add to Watchlist"** button :

```
TypeError at /addwatchlist/10

Field 'id' expected a number but got <Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addwatchlist/10
Django Version:     3.1.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

Field 'id' expected a number but got <Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">.
```

TRACEBACK :

```
watchlist.save()

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
id          10

request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/addwatchlist/10'>

watchlist   Error in formatting: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">.
```

Here is the error that I receive when pressing the **"Remove from Watchlist"** button, note that this is the exact same error I initially received which in turn forced me to try and tweak the way "Add to Watchlist" function :

```
AssertionError at /removewatchlist/1

Watchlist object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/removewatchlist/1
Django Version:     3.1.1
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    

Watchlist object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

TRACEBACK :

```
watchlist.delete()

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
id          1

request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/removewatchlist/1'>

watchlist   <Watchlist: 1 Watchlist ID# None : admin watchlisted : "Iphone 11 Pro">
```

**Models.py** :

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    startingBid = models.IntegerField()
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category_id")
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default='True')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'"{self.title}"'

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    watchlist_listingid = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="watchlist_listingid", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.watchlist_listingid_id} Watchlist ID# {self.id} : {self.user} watchlisted : {self.watchlist_listingid}'
```

**Views.py** :

```
@login_required
def watchlist(request):
    if request.user.username:
        return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "items" : Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username),
        "watchlist_listingid" : Watchlist.objects.values_list('watchlist_listingid', flat=True).filter(user=request.user.username),
        "watchlist_count" : len(Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.username))
    })

def addwatchlist(request, id):

    if request.user.username:
        watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=Listing.objects.filter(id=id).first())
        watchlist.save()
        return redirect('listing', id=id)

    else:
        return render('auctions/watchlist.html', {})

def removewatchlist(request, id):
        if request.user.username:
        # all_entries = Watchlist.objects.values_list('watchlist_listingid', flat=True).filter(user='admin')
        # for i in all_entries:
        #     if i == id:
        #         removeMe = i
        #     else:
        #         removeMe = 'TEST ERROR'
            watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=id)
            watchlist.delete()
            return redirect('listing', id=id)
```

**Urls.py** :

```
path("listing/<int:id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
path("addwatchlist/<int:id>", views.addwatchlist, name="addwatchlist"),
path("removewatchlist/<int:id>", views.removewatchlist, name="removewatchlist")
```

The Add/Remove buttons are hosted on listing.html :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>
            {% if watchlisted %}
            <a href="{% url 'removewatchlist' item.id %}"><button class="btn btn-danger">Remove from watchlist</button></a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'addwatchlist' item.id %}"><button class="btn btn-success">Add to watchlist</button></a>
            {% endif %}
          </p>
    {% endif %}
```

**Questions :**

- Am I complicating myself by using Watchlist.watchlist_listingid as a
  foreign key for Listing? I have seen quite a few other posts where
  people would tend not to use foreign keys at all, though I believe it
  might be not optimized.
- I could eventually be using a form to envelop those buttons but I
  already have a form in my listing.html page (to add comments).
  Tackling the data from a form might be easier though I have not
  managed to find out how to implement several distinct Django forms on
  one HTML page. What do you consider best practice? Forms or direct
  link summoning functions?
- For "Add to Watchlist", why do I obtain `def __str__(self):return f'"{self.title}"'`instead of simply adding a new entry in my
  Watchlist table?
- Finally, for "Remove from Watchlist",why do i receive `"id attribute is set to None"` when I know for a fact that on my example,the
  Listing.id for "Iphone 11 Pro" is 1, and technically speaking,
  Watchlist.id (which does not show at all in my model) is 11 based on
  the Django Admin page. Even hardcoding 11 to force its deletion off
  the Watchlist table still returns this "none" error.

Looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your specific error, the problem is in this line, which should be clear from the error message:

```
watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=Listing.objects.filter(id=id).first())
```

id is expecting an int (the id of a Model instance), but you are actually passing it an object instance of your Listing model; filter() returns a queryset, and then .first() returns the first object in that queryset.

That's why the error is telling you that "field id", which expects an int, is instead getting "<Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">" -- that's an actual instance of your Listing model.

Solution:
Simply adding .id after the .first() should fix your problem, so you are actually passing the id of that object to the id field:

```
watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=Listing.objects.filter(id=id).first().id)
```

That should resolve your specific issue; having said that, though, I highly recommend you use forms for these buttons. Currently, you are allowing modification of the contents of your database in an insecure fashion. Any activity that modifies database content should be delivered as a POST request. You can do this with forms quite easily, even if you aren't using any actual input-fields. The button will submit the empty form as a POST request, you can include a csrf token in your form tag in the template, and the db will be modified accordingly. Another option, if you really don't want to use forms, is to use AJAX calls (via jQuery), which can be sent as POST requests without the use of forms. Explaining how to do that is beyond the scope of this response, but there is plenty of info here on SO.

Lastly, if a Watchlist is tied to a User, you should probably consider a different database schema entirely for getting results-- that is, one that actually ties the User model to the item they are adding to their watchlist (it's possible, though, that I'm misunderstanding your intent here, and maybe you don't want that). You could connect the User model and the Listing models via a Many-to-Many relationship, since a User can 'watchlist' many listings, and a listing can be 'watchlisted' by many users.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution. This worked as expected.

I am still experiencing the error for the removewatchlist function though I know for a fact that the entries are saved appropriately with an autoincrement id. For ex : ID:11 / User:admin / watchlist_listingid : 1.

Would you know the attribute id is supposedly set to none while it seems to be 11 on this occasion? (everytime I add something in the watchlist, the watchlist.id autoincrement by itself naturally by Django despite not showing in my model)

Comment: Swift Update : I managed to make the "removewatchlist" function work by tweaking the way I generated the watchlist variable.

            watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(user=request.user.username, watchlist_listingid=id)
            watchlist.delete()
            return redirect('listing', id=id)

Since it works now, I will not implement a form for it. But i will consider this in the future. Thanks again for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for : "Field 'id' expected a number but got <Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">."**

Simply add .id after .first()

```
watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=Listing.objects.filter(id=id).first() = <Listing: "Gloss + Repair Spray">

watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=Listing.objects.filter(id=id).first().id) = 6 (which is the ID in my database)
```

**Fix for : Watchlist object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.**

```
watchlist = Watchlist.objects.get(user=request.user.username, watchlist_listingid=id)
```

GET the whole row in your table and assign it to a variable before using delete()

Instead of the faulty :

```
watchlist = Watchlist(user=request.user.username,watchlist_listingid_id=id)
```

Finally, I found out that to **use different Django Forms in the same HTML page**, you can s**et the action of the form to a path url in URLS.PY which would then trigger a special functions in Views.py.**